# How to remove all characters before last matching character in Lua

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

So i'm a little bit confused about Lua pattern matching. I have a script to log history of videos played with MPV, but i don't need full path there, just filename is enough, so i wanted to remove all everything before last `/` char. In Python i would do simple

`filename = re.sub(r'.*/', '', path)`

But i failed horribly using Lua pattern matching. How does one do that?

Example input with desirable output:

```
>>> path = "/some/path/to/file.mkv"
>>> filename = re.sub(r'.*/', '', path)
>>> filename
'file.mkv'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems i have figured it out by myself, oh well. Used this kind of pattern:

```
path = "/path/to/some/file"
filename = path:gsub(".*/", "")
```

filename now contains only "file".

EDIT: As suggested, i changed `path:gsub("(.*).*/",'')` to `path:gsub(".*/", "")` instead since it's much more readable syntax .

Comment: You can shorten that to `path:gsub(".*/", "")`. Another approach is `path:match("[^/]+$")`.

Comment: `path:gsub(".*/", "")` definitely looks better, and is much more readable as well. Will definitely use that one in the future, thank you!